# How to keep sequence of XML tags even add/remove a tag using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am looking for a solution in python for the following.
The following is my current xml file format.

```
<step_1>abc</step_1>
<step_2>efg</step_2>
<step_3>hij</step_3>
<step_4>klm</step_4>
```

I want to add/delete a tag in between the first and last and maintain the naming of tag in sequence. That is for example: if i delete `<step_2>efg</step_2>` then the result should be as follows

```
<step_1>abc</step_1>
<step_2>hij</step_2>
<step_3>klm</step_3>
```

Is there any solution for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For your requirement, you may need to extract all the data first, modify the data, and then rebuild XML.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that *tag* attribute of an XML element **can be modified**,
at least using *lxml*.

Another reason that I based my solution on *lxml* is that it contains *xpath*
method, which is needed here.

To start with, assume that you have added or deleted some *step_...* elements
to your source tree, there are also elements with other names, and now the
whole tree contains:

```
<main>
  <xx>
    <other>a1</other>
    <step_1>abc</step_1>
    <step_3>hij</step_3>
    <other>a2</other>
    <step_4>klm</step_4>
    <step_6>xyz</step_6>
  </xx>
  <yy>
    <step_1>abc_2</step_1>
    <step_7>xyz_2</step_7>
    <step_2>efg_2</step_2>
    <other>a3</other>
    <step_4>klm_2</step_4>
  </yy>
</main>
```

I read the above content from a file:

```
from lxml import etree as et

parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = et.parse('Input.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
```

Then the idea is to:

- Find each "parent" element containng at least one *step_...* element.
- Loop over its children with name starting from *step*.
- Change its name (*tag*) to *step_* + consecutive number.

The code to do it, with test printouts, is:

```
for el in root.xpath(".//*[starts-with(name(), 'step')]/.."):
    tg = el.tag
    print(f'Parent: {tg:7}')
    i = 0
    for el2 in el.xpath("*[starts-with(name(), 'step')]"):
        i += 1
        tg2 = el2.tag
        tt = el2.text
        if tt is None: tt = ''
        newName = f'step_{i}'
        print(f'  Child {i}: {tg2:7}  {tt:8} -> {newName}')
        el2.tag = newName
```

It prints:

```
Parent: xx     
  Child 1: step_1   abc      -> step_1
  Child 2: step_3   hij      -> step_2
  Child 3: step_4   klm      -> step_3
  Child 4: step_6   xyz      -> step_4
Parent: yy     
  Child 1: step_1   abc_2    -> step_1
  Child 2: step_7   xyz_2    -> step_2
  Child 3: step_2   efg_2    -> step_3
  Child 4: step_4   klm_2    -> step_4
```

When you now print the content:

```
print(et.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

the result is:

```
<main>
  <xx>
    <other>a1</other>
    <step_1>abc</step_1>
    <step_2>hij</step_2>
    <other>a2</other>
    <step_3>klm</step_3>
    <step_4>xyz</step_4>
  </xx>
  <yy>
    <step_1>abc_2</step_1>
    <step_2>xyz_2</step_2>
    <step_3>efg_2</step_3>
    <other>a3</other>
    <step_4>klm_2</step_4>
  </yy>
</main>
```

So as you can see:

- *step_...* elements have been "renumerated", from *1* within their parent.
- All other elements keep their position and content.